# Is there any way to write same column many times with sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

There is a column that stores numbers and another column stores state. The state can store 1(one) or 0(zero).

I tried case when clause and subquery for every state. But this subquery is so long. I want to shorten the query.

```
select (select sum(number) from account where state = 1) as activesum, (select sum(number) from account where state=0) as passivesum from dual
```

PassiveSum    ActiveSum

---

1458,6      152,3

I want this query to work like this 
  select sum(number) active, sum(number) passive from account where state in (0,1)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `state` on only takes on these two values, you can do:

```
select sum(state) as active_sum,
       sum(1 - state) as passivesum 
from account;
```

If you want the sum of the numbers, use `case`:

```
select sum(case when state = 1 then number end) as active_sum,
       sum(case when state = 0 then number end) as passivesum
from account;
```

Comment: I need numbers column not state column.

Comment: Thank you. This answer is exactly what i want.